# Output file formatting

Tags: python

I want my output file format to be like this :

```
file_out.write("{0},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16},{17},{18},{19},{20},{21},{22},{23},{24},{25},{26},{27},{28},{29}\n".format(*frequency_count(seq)))
```

Basically I want to write a file that contains item one until 30 . I tried to do something like this

```
file_out.write("{0}:{29}\n".format(*frequency_count(seq)))
```

but i only get the 1st item and the last item. 
How do I write such that my output file contains all items without having to write all of them in my command.

The items are integers from a list of something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the first 30 items returned from **frequency_count** comma-delimited, try the following:

```
file_out.write(','.join(map(str,frequency_count(seq)[:30])) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply join items by `,`:

```
file_out.write(','.join(frequency_count(seq)))
```

You may also need to cast list items to string before joining:

```
file_out.write(','.join(map(str, frequency_count(seq))))
```

Comment: owh the items are integers. So I get this error when I tried your code TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(30):
    write_me += '{%d},' % i

write_me += '\n'
file_out.write(write_me).format(*frequency_count(seq))
```

It should work just ask questions below.

EDIT:  Just realized I misunderstood the question disregard thsi